# How to loop through all the tables in a schema and update the MIN(primary_key column) value of all tables with the same value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

looking for an approach to update the min value of the primary key column of all tables in a schema, i am able to get the values of the primary key column names and table names from my required schema but not sure how to use that select query output to update the values using PLSQL

not able to find the right approach for the problem
Edit 1:
with the help of the below answer i came up with the below code , but now facing an error missing "equal sign" in the update block eventhough the equal to sign is there, can anyone please help with the issue?

```
--DECLARE
...
--SELECT STATEMENT
...
     loop
     execute immediate 'select max(' || cur_r.column_name ||') from ' ||
                          cur_r.table_name into l_max;
l_str:=     ' update '||cur_r.table_name||' SET max(' || cur_r.column_name ||') = '|| l_max;
begin
         execute immediate l_str;
end;
dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||' -> max value = '|| l_max);
     end loop;
   end;
```

EDIT 2:
trying to test the code with one table , the below sql code block is getting succeeded but the update is not happening in the table,but when running the update query with hardcoded values , the table is updating successfully.

```
Begin 
select MAX(STATUSID) into max_1 from STATUS;
l_str:=     ' update STATUS SET STATUSID = '' || max_1 || '' where STATUSID = ''||max_1||''';
begin
         execute immediate l_str;
         dbms_output.put_line(max_1);
end;
end;
```

working query:
MAX(STATUSID)= Y

```
update STATUS SET STATUSID = 'Y' where STATUSID = 'Y';
```

Comment: Your updated code generates update statements like `update sometable SET max(somecolumn) = 1234`, which fails with "ORA-00927: missing equal sign" because it expects a column name followed by `=` after the `set` keyword (e.g. `update t set c = 1234`). If it could report two errors, the next would be that you don't have a column named `max`. I recommend testing the syntax you plan to use before building the dynamic code.

Comment: trying to test the code with one table , the above added plsql code block is getting succeeded but the update is not happening in the table,but when running the update query with hardcoded values , the table is updating successfully not sure what the issue with the plsql block is

Comment: The second block is missing some quotes. To quote a `'` character you need to double it to `''`. Since you are updating each value to itself, I'm not sure you need to quote it twice as you can just set statusid = statusid. Also you have stray `begin` and `end` keywords which won't break anything but just complicate the code unnecessarily. I recommend always laying out code neatly so that the structure is easier to check visually.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to update primary key column value? Are you sure that this is a good idea? Because,

- what do you plan to do with foreign key constraints? You can't update primary key that is being referenced from other tables
- what about composite primary keys (the ones that are made up of two or more columns)?
- what about different datatypes? Primary keys can be NUMBERs, but also e.g. VARCHAR2s or DATEs.

Anyway: here's example which shows how to do that - **dynamic SQL**. Read comments within code.

In my sample schema, there are several tables with primary keys:

```
SQL> select c.table_name, c.column_name, p.data_type
  2  from user_cons_columns c join
  3       user_constraints t on t.constraint_name = c.constraint_name join
  4       user_tab_columns p on p.table_name = c.table_name
  5                         and p.column_name = c.column_name
  6  where t.constraint_type = 'P';

TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE
--------------- --------------- ---------------
DEPT            DEPTNO          NUMBER   --> foreign key from EMP won't allow update
EMP             EMPNO           NUMBER
COUNTRIES       CODE            VARCHAR2 --> datatype will rule out this PK
TEST            ID              NUMBER
```

OK, let's go:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    l_old_pk_value number;
  4    l_new_pk_value number := -1;
  5  begin
  6    -- find primary keys whose datatype is NUMBER on position 1
  7    for cur_r in (select c.table_name, c.column_name
  8                  from user_cons_columns c join
  9                       user_constraints t on t.constraint_name = c.constraint_name join
 10                       user_tab_columns p on p.table_name = c.table_name
 11                                         and p.column_name = c.column_name
 12                  where t.constraint_type = 'P'
 13                    and p.data_type = 'NUMBER'
 14                    and c.position = 1)
 15    loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line('Working on ' || cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name);
 17      -- find minimum value of primary key column
 18      l_str := 'select min(' || cur_r.column_name ||')' ||
 19               ' from ' ||cur_r.table_name;
 20      execute immediate l_str into l_old_pk_value;
 21
 22      -- update minimum value of the primary key column to L_NEW_PK_VALUE
 23      l_str := 'update ' || cur_r.table_name || ' set ' ||
 24               cur_r.column_name || ' = ' || l_new_pk_value ||
 25               ' where ' ||cur_r.column_name || ' = ' || l_old_pk_value;
 26      -- report if something goes wrong
 27      begin
 28        execute immediate l_str;
 29      exception
 30        when others then
 31          dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||': '|| sqlerrm);
 32      end;
 33    end loop;
 34  end;
 35  /
```

Outcome:

```
Working on DEPT.DEPTNO
DEPT.DEPTNO: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_EMP_DEPT) violated - child record found
Working on EMP.EMPNO
Working on TEST.ID

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As I said, `DEPT` failed on foreign key constraint. `EMP` and `TEST` were updated.

```
SQL> select * from emp where empno = -1;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        -1 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
        -1 Littlefoot
         2 Bigfoot

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply , actually i am trying to update the primarykey value with the same value so that the value is not changed, the purpose is to check the modification time stamp column in all the tables if it is working, i used your code to come up with a solution but facing an error missing equal sign in the update part, do you know what the cause of the error is? as the "=" sign is present.....i edited the code into the main question block

Comment: If you got errors, then don't EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements, but **display** them first using `dbms_output.put_line(l_str);` - then you'd see what's wrong. Fix the error and then execute L_STR.